# input type="range" выглядит как обычное поле для ввода

Tags: html

Когда я ввожу код `<input type="range">` у меня отображается обычное поле для ввода, как на фото. Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу понять в чем проблема.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: @Igor, вроде doctype в реальности на поддержку браузерами не влияет.

Comment: Да,  в <!DOCTYPE>.

Comment: и что в нём да?

Comment: Нормально задайте вопрос и я нормального на него отвечу.

Comment: Какой браузер-то?

Comment: Вопрос решен. На input влиял подключенный плагин. Я удалила этот плагин и все стало ОК.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если браузер не поддерживает данный тип инпута, то показывается обычный текстовый. Однако, `range` [поддерживается](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range) довольно давно, поэтому предположу, что в коде просто опечатка, например, одна из букв кириллическая.

```html
<input type="range"> <input type="nevermind">
```

Comment: Все написано верно, без опечаток.